# Interweaving two pictures

Tags: python, jython, crop, image, getpixel

I am trying to interweave two pictures.

Picture 1 [image: Picture 1]  Picture 2       [image: Picture 2]    To This     [image: REsult]

```
def interWeave(pic, picture):
  w=getWidth(pic)
  h=getHeight(pic)
  newPic=makeEmptyPicture(w,h)
  for x in range (0,w):
    for y in range (0,h):
      p=getPixel(pic,x,y)
      p2=getPixel(picture,x,y)
      newPxl=getPixel(newPic,x,y)

      if (x>=0 and x<20) or (x>=40 and x<60)or (x>=80 and x<=100):
        color = getColor(p)

      else:
        color=getColor(p2)
        setColor(newPxl, color) 
  return (newPic)
```

But I get this:

[image: newpic]

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (x>=0 and x<20) or (x>=40 and x<60)or (x>=80 and x<=100):
        color = getColor(p)

      else:
        color=getColor(p2)
        setColor(newPxl, color)
```

If your indentatin is right, you only `setColor` in the else block. So the range from 0~20, 40~60, 80~100 will be blank.